# C++ Text based RPG game map travel problems

Tags: c++

I tried a lot of things before coming here but I just can't seem to fix my problem!

I have a randomly generated map which is an array that stores the tile objects. This is randomly generated at start-up.
I have the player co-ordinates set up with functions that alter the co-ordinates based on map travel.
I then have a function that returns what is stored in the map array based on the player co-ordinates.
In the constructor for the co-ordinates I have had to set the x and y pos to 0 or the code won't run.

So when I run the code, it displays the first tile fine, and when I travel N,E,S or W it displays the new tile, however the x and y co-ordinates just stay 0, they don't adjust as I travel, I was thinking maybe it's something to do with the constructor here:

```
Player::Player()
{
    posX = 0;
    posY = 0;
}
Player::~Player()
{
}

int Player::getX()
{
    return Player::posX;
}
int Player::getY()
{
    return Player::posY;
}
int Player::changeX(int xChange)
{
    int x = getX();
    x = x + xChange;
    posX = x;
    return x;
}
int Player::changeY(int yChange)
{
    int y = getY();
    y = y + yChange;
    posY = y;
    return y;
}
```

And here is the part of the code that displays the tile and co-ordinates.

```
Terrain* GameMenu::playerPos()
{

    Player display;
    Map mapArray;

    return mapArray.map[display.getX()][display.getY()];
}

int GameMenu::doMenu()
{
    while(int loop = 1)
    {
        loop = 1;
        Player display;
        cout << display.getY() << display.getY() <<endl << endl;
        cout << "You are currently in an area that looks like a " 
                << playerPos()->getName()<<endl<<endl;

        cout << "What would you like to do next?"<<endl<<endl;
        cout << "1. Rest" << endl;
        cout << "2. Buy food" << endl;
        cout << "3. Travel" << endl;
        cout << "4. Search" << endl;
        cout << "5. Hunt" << endl;
```

Sorry if it's a little vague, it's the first time I've done something like this, and every bit of help is much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're creating a new player right before you print the coordinates, which sets that player's position to 0,0

Comment: Do you mean the constructor? I thought it could be that, but I need to set the initial co-ordinates for the player somewhere, but I need it to only run once, and not reset to 0,0 every time, do you know of a way I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

The Player is being repeatedly created and destroyed as a local variable. It should be longer-lived, perhaps a member of Game or GameMenu, or a local variable in your main() function which you pass by reference into your Game object.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try this out now. Also my question was downvoted, I'm not complaining, I'm just wondering if there is something I should do differently in the future when asking a question.

Comment: And you have the same problem with your `mapArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Terrain* GameMenu::PlayerPos()` is like Dori the fish.  It is not storing the map - it recreates one every time you call it and then deletes it when the function ends.  You tell it where the map should move, it stores the new map, and then the function is over - and `display` and `mapArray` fall out of scope.  Your data is gone forever.

To store the data across multiple function calls, consider making the map and the player a member of the function `main()` or the class `GameMenu` like this:

```
class GameMenu
{
public:
     GameMenu()
     {
          m_map = new Map();
          m_player = new Player();
     }
     ~GameMenu()
     {
          delete m_map;
          delete m_player;
     }
     inline Terrain *GetPlayerPos() {return mapArray.map[m_player.getX()][m_player.getY()];};
private:
     Map *m_map;
     Player *m_player;
};
```

Also, the code you have for `Player::changeX` and `Player::changeY` is very overcomplicated.  Why don't you just do this?

```
int Player::changeX(int delta)
{
     posX += delta;
     return posX;
}
int Player::changeY(int delta)
{
     posY += delta;
     return posY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why I didn't see this before.
If I do this, will I need to adjust anything in all of the tile files?
I have 8 different tiles like Farmland.h etc.